# Generalizing Polygons to MultiPolygons in GeoDjango?

Tags: postgis, qgis, polygon, geodjango

I set up a model with `models.PolygonField` in geodjango, using postgres as database. I try to import shp into postgres. The problem is, shp (compiled with QGIS) mixes polygon and multipolygon, hence it always fails to do the export because of the constraint check `enforce_geotype`.

Is there a way to clear the constraint, so as to store both multipolygon and polygon type data?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The SQL to drop the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE myapp_mymodel DROP CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_mygeom;
```

Or to alter it to allow both Polygons & MultiPolygons:

```
ALTER TABLE myapp_mymodel DROP CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_mygeom;
ALTER TABLE myapp_mymodel ADD CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_mygeom CHECK (geometrytype(mygeom) = 'POLYGON'::text OR geometrytype(mygeom) = 'MULTIPOLYGON'::text OR mygeom IS NULL);
```

These SQL statements could be run from a [South migration](http://south.aeracode.org) or an [initial-data SQL script](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#database-backend-specific-sql-data).

Another option is to make it a `GeometryField` in your Django model definition - this will allow it to store any geometry type.

Or, override the `save()` method on your model to force everything to be a MultiPolygon:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.contrib.gis import geos

class MyModel(models.Model):
  mygeom = models.MultiPolygonField()
  ... other fields....

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # if mygeom ends up as a Polgon, make it into a MultiPolygon
    if self.mygeom and isinstance(self.mygeom, geos.Polygon):
      self.mygeom = geos.MultiPolygon(self.mygeom)

    super(MyModel).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: The last method might be a good choice

Answer (score 6):

I know this is old, but I just ran into this issue myself and had problems using the above suggested solutions:

- Using `GeometryField` makes it difficult to use the built-in `OSMGeoAdmin` class. The code in `templates/gis/admin/openlayers.js` (and `contrib/gis/admin/widgets.py` and probably other places I missed) frequently assumes that the geometry is a point, line, polygon, or collection, and never accounts for generic geometries. This isn't necessarily important or insurmountable, but if you were planning on using the built-in admin you might be disappointed.
- Overriding `save()` doesn't work because the type-checking happens sooner, in the model's `__set__()`.

My current solution is explicitly coercing all of my `Polygon`s into `MultiPolygon`s when importing and saving my data. I might override `__set__()` if this becomes cumbersome.

Coerce this way:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import MultiPolygon

multipolygon = MultiPolygon([polygon])
```

Answer (score 6):

longish workaround

one could use fromstr()

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import fromstr

p = Polygon()
# this seems to work correctly
mp = MultiPolygon(fromstr(str(p)),)

model1.geom_field = mp

model1.save()
```